# UIView with xib ignores size classes

Tags: objective-c, layout, xib, uiwindow, size-classes

I'm working on custom notification view, which must show up over everything. To achive this
I've implemented it as a subview of separate UIWindow and everything works fine except for layout: I use size classes, and layout just ignores it.
Here is the code 
I use to setup my view:

```
NotificationView *notificationView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotificationView"
                                                                    owner:self
                                                                  options:nil] firstObject];
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
// Additional window setup..

[window addSubview:notificationView];
```

Comment: Have you try to add notificationView inside your self.view?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala, I have no view controller

Comment: This is not your first screen right.You need to subview inside currently running screen.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala what do you mean by screen? UIScreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: I figured it out

I was adding my notificationView to UIWindow directly, in this case size classes get ignored. Then I tried to instantiate corresponding UIViewController subclass (though I don't really need it) and add it to its self.view in this case size classes work as expected.

**Conclusion: View must be in UIViewController view hierarchy to support size classes.**

Answer (score -1):

You need to add constraints, in code, to relate the two views after adding one to the other.

Read here for more information:

https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/

Comment: I have them added in xib

Comment: Add constraints in code, when you add it to the superview, the automatically generated constraints maintain its current frame. When the superview resizes, they resize it according to the autoresizing mask